# Can't send java mail to smtp host

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, camunda, camunda-modeler

I  have this   class  inside my camunda   environment(and i  use  this   class  like as  service  task inside  camunda modeller):

```
public class SendMails implements JavaDelegate{

    String  text,from,password;
    Object jsonObject1=new JSONObject();
 public static void send( final String from, final String password,String to,String sub,String msg){  
     Properties props = new Properties();    
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");    
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");    
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",    
               "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");    
     //get Session   
     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,    
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {    
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {    
      return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);  
      }    
     });    
     //compose message    
     try {    
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);    
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));    
      message.setSubject(sub);    
      message.setText(msg);    
      //send message  
      Transport.send(message);    
      System.out.println("message sent successfully");    
     } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}    

}  

    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

        text = execution.getVariable("selectedDocuments").toString();
        send("demo@camunda.org","xxxxx","test@gmail.com","hello javatpoint","How r u?");  

        }
    }
```

HERE   IS  MY  POM:

```
<dependencies>  
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
      <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency> 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

but  when   i try  to send   message  i  got  errors  like this:

> Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to
>   host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   ge.psda.camunda.sendMails.SendMails.send(SendMails.java:40)   ... 208
>   more

P.S  i  have enabled  less secure  up  in my mail  but  this can't  helped  me  what should  i  change  to  be able  to send  mail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unalbe to connect smtp.gmail.com at 465 in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775391/unalbe-to-connect-smtp-gmail-com-at-465-in-a-loop)

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Then, upgrade to the [current version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).  Finally, the JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide credentials for the sender. You have configured(properties) it for gmail. Actually you have configure properties for your smtp server from where you are sending email.

And dependencies you need:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have added   this  dependencies and  mail   confiuration in application.properties  but  nothing  helps